# exited: scrapy (exit status 0; not expected)

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, supervisord

I try to run bash script that launch many spiders in my Docker container.
My `supervisor.conf` that placed in "`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`" looke like that:

```
[program:scrapy]                                                            
command=/tmp/start_spider.sh
autorestart=false
startretries=0
stderr_logfile=/tmp/start_spider.err.log
stdout_logfile=/tmp/start_spider.out.log
```

but supervisor return this errors:

> 2015-08-21 10:50:30,466 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in
>   config file)
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:30,466 WARN Included extra file
>   "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/tor.conf" during parsing
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:30,478 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:30,478 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without
>   any HTTP authentication checking
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:30,478 INFO supervisord started with pid 5
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:31,481 INFO spawned: 'scrapy' with pid 8
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:31,555 INFO exited: scrapy (exit status 0; not
>   expected)
>
> 2015-08-21 10:50:32,557 INFO gave up: scrapy entered FATAL state, too
>   many start retries too quickly

And my program stop to running. But if I manually run my program , it works very well ...

How to resolve this ? any ideas?

Comment: what does start_spider.sh look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. For the `supervisor.conf`, change

```
[program:scrapy]                                                       
command=/tmp/start_spider.sh
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

by:

```
[program:scrapy]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec /tmp/start_spider.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 -DFOREGROUND"
autostart=true
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my code:

start_spider.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# list letter
parseLetter=('a' 'b')


# change path
cd $path/scrapy/scrapyTodo/scrapyTodo

tLen=${#parseLetter[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
do
    scrapy crawl root -a alpha=${parseLetter[$i]} &
done
```

here is my scrapy code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.selector import Selector
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tools import sendEmail
from tools import ElasticAction
from tools import runlog
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from datetime import datetime
import re

class studentCrawler(BaseSpider):
    # Crawling Start
    CrawlSpider.started_on = datetime.now()

    name = "root"


    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0

    allowed_domains = ['website.com']

    ES_Index = "website"
    ES_Type = "root"
    ES_Ip = "127.0.0.1"

    child_type = "level1"

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 302, 503, 999, 200] #add any other code you need

    es = ElasticAction(ES_Index, ES_Type, ES_Ip)

    # Init
    def __init__(self, alpha=''):

        base_domain = 'https://www.website.com/directory/student-' + str(alpha) + "/"

        self.start_urls = [base_domain]
        super(CompanyCrawler, self).__init__(self.start_urls)


    def is_empty(self, any_structure):
        """
        Function that allow to check if the data is empty or not
        :arg any_structure: any data
        """
        if any_structure:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        main method that parse the web page
        :param response:
        :return:
        """

        if response.status == 404:
            self.es.insertIntoES(response.url, "False")
        if str(response.status) == "503":
            self.es.insertIntoES(response.url, "False")
        if response.status == 999:
            self.es.insertIntoES(response.url, "False")

        if str(response.status) == "200":
            # Selector
            sel = Selector(response)

            self.es.insertIntoES(response.url, "True")
            body = self.getAllTheUrl('u'.join(sel.xpath(".//*[@id='seo-dir']/div/div[3]").extract()).strip(),response.url )


    def getAllTheUrl(self, data, parent_id):
        dictCompany = dict()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            self.es.insertChildAndParent(self.child_type, str(a['href']), "False", parent_id)
```

I discovered that BeautifulSoup not working When the spiders are Launched by supervisor....